# I want to Modifying bar-position in matplotlib bar-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I find an answer below
[Modifying bar-width and bar-position in matplotlib bar-plot (looping over containers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643281/modifying-bar-width-and-bar-position-in-matplotlib-bar-plot-looping-over-contai)
but I really do not know what "sizes" mean when I run the code, python told me, "sizes" is unknown, the code is below, anyone can help me?

```
 for container in axes.containers:
        for i, child in enumerate(container.get_children()):
            child.set_x(df.index[i] - sizes[i]/2)
            plt.setp(child, width=sizes[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you refer to, `sizes` is a list or array of widths that the person wants their bars to be.

When you are using the code you should define such a list or array, based on the bar widths you want.

Hope this helps.